# How to check the count and based on that query

Tags: mysql

I have a table employees and a table department. Each employee is linked to a department id. The fields of the employee table are

```
    EMPLOYEE
    ssn, fname, lname, dept_id


    DEPARTMENT
    dept_id, dept_name
```

So my problem is that I need to pick the employee name and last name if there are more than 3 employees in a specific department. I am not sure the best way to do this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is MySQL dislikes queries with subqueries that access same tables.

```
SELECT d.dept_name, GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(E.FNAME,' ',E.LNAME) ORDER BY E.LNAME 
SEPARATOR ',' ),
FROM DEPARTMENT D JOIN EMPLOYEE E USING(dept_id)
GROUP BY dept_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3;
```

This solution would provide a list of employess per row per department.
For instance:

'IT', 'Micky Mouse, Tom Jones'
'HR', 'Emily Bronte'

If you prefer, you can change the separator character used in the employees list with SEPARATOR.

Comment: +1 ,can be optimize by using `CONCAT_WS(' ',E.fname,E.lname)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT lname, fname
FROM Employee
WHERE dept_id
IN (

SELECT dept_id
FROM Employee
GROUP BY dept_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3)
```

Comment: Oops, first version of the query had a mistake in the inner query. Fixed it now.